# Creating nested relationships with an ORM and minimizing queries

Tags: php, codeigniter, orm, codeigniter-datamapper

### Edit 3

After reading a boat load I really don't think with any ORM or system in general it is possible to build the relationships of organized objects like I want in fewer queries that I am using. If any can provide an example of it being possible I would kiss you.

In ***Edit 2*** The nested for loops I think is the best solution running

```
Total_queries = 1 + 2(Slides_in_project) + Shapes_in_project
                |                |                        \
  Query to get project           |                         \
                                 |                          \
        Query to get slides and double because of points     \
                                                              \
                                              Get all the shapes in the project
```

I would love a better example because to populate simple projects I would probably be running 200-500 queries. This is bad.

### Edit 2

Well I have been playing with this for a while now and I have some results but I do not think they are the "RIGHT" way and that matters to me a lot.  What I do is I use the `where_related` method to get the right objects but I think my query count is still pretty high and I know an ORM can do better. When I use the where related to create the proper hierarchy I have to use nested `foreach` loops and I don't like that. That means useless querying.

Here is the solution I came up with

```
function get_project_points($link_id)
{
    echo "<pre>";
    foreach($this->where('link_id', $link_id)->get()->slide->where_related('project', 'id', $this)->get() as $slide){
        echo $slide->id."<br>";
        foreach($slide->shape->where_related('slide', 'id', $slide->id)->get() as $shape){
            echo "\t".$shape->id."<br>";
            foreach ($shape->point->where_related('shape', 'id', $shape->id)->get() as $point) {
                echo "\t\t".$point->id."<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs a nice tiered structure and as you can see it would be easy to replace the echos with object/array population.

What I would rather have though is one chained command that did the same thing if possible that way scoping isn't an issue either.

Some chain more resembling

```
$this->where('link_id', $link_id)->get()
    ->slide->where_related('project', 'id', $this)->get()
    ->shape->where_related('slide', 'id', $slide->id)->get()
    ->point->where_related('shape', 'id', $shape->id)->get()
```

That of course does not achieve anywhere near the same results as the nested foreach loops but what I would like to know is it possible to chain relationships and populate objects without nested foreach

So I just did some profiling and the nested foreach loops generate 63 queries on a small project, and take almost half a second to generate results.  This is really too slow. There must be a better query.

__________Edit 1

All the below information is great but I have been playing with it and I cannot seem to get any relationship to work let alone a 3 tiered one. I have tried just about everything I can think of and read the doc's but for somereason my brain doesn't like the ORM.

I would like to just echo the id's of all `slides` in a `project`.  I will give a list of what I have tried with no avail. My model structure is the same as below I am just adding methodes.

```
class Project extends DataMapper {
    var $has_many = array("slide");

    function get_project_slides($link_id)
    {
        $this->where('link_id', $link_id)
            ->where_related('slides', 'project_id' 
                $this->where('link_id', $link_id)->get()->id
            )
        ->get();
    }

}
```

And I have tried what I would think is the logical opposite in the Slide Method.

What am I doing wrong... How do you structure ORM relationships?

---

### Original Question

I am using an ORM for the first time and I am having huge problems visualizing how to structure the code to pull data from the relationships.

I am using [DataMapper](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/) as my ORM with [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/). I have the installation working just fine and I read all the docs, I just cannot get my head around how to get information in controllers

```
+-----------+    +------------+    +---------+    +----------+
|  projects |    | slides     |    | shapes  |    |  points  |
+-----------+    +------------+    +---------+    +----------+
|    id     |    |  id        |    | id      |    | id       |
+-----------+    | project_id |    |slide_id |    | shape_id |
                 +------------+    +---------+    | x        |
                                                  | y        |
                                                  +----------+
```

Models -

**project.php**

```
class Project extends DataMapper {
    var $has_many = array("slide");
}

//  End of project.php
//  Location: ./application/models/project.php
```

**slide.php**

```
<?php

class Slide extends DataMapper {
    var $has_many = array("shape");
    var $has_one = array("project");
}

//  End of slide.php
//  Location: ./application/models/slide.php
```

**shape.php**

```
<?php

class Shape extends DataMapper {
    var $has_many = array("point");
    var $has_one = array("slide");
}

//  End of shape.php
//  Location: ./application/models/shape.php
```

**point.php**

```
<?php

class Point extends DataMapper {
    var $has_one = array("shape");
}

//  End of point.php
//  Location: ./application/models/point.php
```

The above should create a decending one->many relationship between projects->slides->shapes->points

How do you start to deal with information? When I was not using an ORM I handled all data processing in the Model is this incorrect for the ORM Models? Say you wanted to get all the points in all the shapes in project 1 how would you go about structuring such a call?

I don't really need specific code if you want that would be helpful.  What I really need is some ideas on how to visualize how to tier the objects so you can deal with each at any tier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'm sorry to break this to you , but CodeIgniter's DataMapper is actually a variation of ActiveRecord pattern.

If you care, you compare the real [DataMapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) pattern with its counterpart - [ActiveRecord](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html). In short - difference is in fact that in DM pattern you Domain Object is unaware of type ( and even the existence ) of storage. It is used in manner like `$mapper->store( $user );`.

> "Favor object composition over class
>   inheritance." © [GoF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns_%28book%29)

That said..

---

If i read the examples right then it should work like this:
( i am assuming that relationships between 'entities' are already established )

```
class Project extends DataMapper
{
   // --- the rest of your stuff 

   public function get_all_points()
   {
      $points = array();

      $slides = $this->slide->get()->all;


      foreach ( $slides as $slide )
      {
         $shapes = $slide->shape->get()->all;

         foreach ( $shapes as $shape )
         {
            $points = array_merge( $point = $shape->point->get();
         }
      }

      return $points;

   }


}
```

Then you can use something like

```
$project = new Project;
$all_points = $project->where( 'id' , 1 )->get_all_points();

foreach ( $all_points as $point )
{
   $point->x = 0;
   $point->save();
}
```

This **should** gather all th points that are related to project with ID 1, and set the X value to 0 and store each in the database .. not that any sane person would do it.

---

I am not using any sort of ORM, that's why i really hope i got this wrong, because this looks to me like an abomination.

Comment: That is really ugly.  I was hoping an orm would clean things up :/

Comment: @austinbv i am not user of CI. It's quite possible, that this all is bullsh*t and i am doing it wrong. But this is how i understood the documentation ( from source in *DataMapper/application/controllers/examples.php* ).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how Datamapper does it but I have a custom GenericObject model for Codeigniter that does ORM like this:

```
class Article extends GenericObject
{
    public $relationships = array ( "has_many" => array ("comments"), "has_one" => array ("users") );
}
class Comments extends GenericObject
{
    public $relationships = array ( "belongs_to" => array ("articles", "users"), "has_one" => array ("users") );
}
class Users extends GenericObject
{
    public $relationships = array ( "has_many" => array ("comments", "articles") );
}
```

If I want to get everything from a User then I can just do something like:

```
$User = new User( $some_user_id );
$User->boot_relations("all");

foreach ($User->Comments as $Comment)
{
    echo $Comment->title."<br />";
    echo $Comment->body."<br />";
    echo "written by ".$User->username;
}
```

So it can be fairly elegant (or at least I like to think so).

Answer (score 0):

With most relational data, I typically lazy-load objects at they are needed.  I'm not a PHP developer, but here's what I would do in pseudo-code.

```
class Projects {
    var slides = null;
    function getSlides() {
        if(slides == null) {
            slides = getSlidesForProject(this.id);
        }
        return slides;
    }
}

class Slides {
    var shapes = null;
    function getShapes() {
        if(shapes == null) {
            shapes = getShapesForSlide(this.id);
        }
        return slides;
    }
}

class Shapes {
    //... same as Projects.getSlides and Slides.getShapes
}
```

Unfortunately, this causes multiple calls to the database if you needed to get all Points for a Project.

With any MVC solution, I recommend going with a light Controller and a heavy Model to make code reuse and testing easier.

Answer (score 0):

First off : I don't know anything about CI's own ORM implementation, but when I see what you are doing, either it's missing some functionality or you're using it in the wrong way (from your edit #2).

In [Propel](http://www.propelorm.org) however (just mentioning this because that's what I use most if the time, [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org) is another good alternative) these things are easily done, especially in the new 1.6 branch, using fluent interfaces. Just check out the [docs on Relationships](http://www.propelorm.org/wiki/Documentation/1.6/Relationships). Doesn't that look like something you'd want to use? :p

Comment: Could you give me an example of how you would set up such a relationship with docterine.

Comment: Just read the docs, there are lots of examples : http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/working-with-associations.html (and as I said : I prefer Propel, I just mentioned Doctrine for completeness - they are afaik still the major ORM libs for PHP).

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to retrieve one project with all the associated points, given  the constraints between each table.

Check this sqlFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ed46/2

**Schema cration:**

```
CREATE TABLE project
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     name varchar(20)
    );

CREATE TABLE slide
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     name varchar(20),
     project_id int
    );

CREATE TABLE shape
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     name varchar(20),
     slide_id int
    );


CREATE TABLE point
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     name varchar(20),
     shape_id int
    );
```

**Request:**

```
select project.id as project_id, project.name as project_name,
       slide.id as   slide_id,   slide.name as   slide_name,
       shape.id as   shape_id,   shape.name as   shape_name,
       point.id as   point_id,   point.name as   point_name

from project

left join slide on slide.project_id = project.id
left join shape on shape.slide_id   = slide.id
left join point on point.shape_id   = shape.id

where project.id = 1
```

**It returns something like this:**

```
PROJECT_ID PROJECT_NAME SLIDE_ID SLIDE_NAME SHAPE_ID SHAPE_NAME POINT_ID POINT_NAME
1          fst_project  1       fst_slide   1        fst_shape  1        first_pt
1          fst_project  1       fst_slide   1        fst_shape  2        2nd_pt
...
```

By processing this output, you could construct an object tree that is like you want, everything in 1 query. But this post-processing may take some time. You would have to loop through each point.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Granada](https://github.com/Surt/Granada).

From the readme:

```
class User extends Model {
         public static $_table = 'user';

         public function post(){
               return $this->has_many('Post');
         }
         public function avatar(){
               return $this->has_one('Avatar');
         }
   }
```

You can include relationships inside your relationships !

```
$user_list = Model::factory('User')->with(array('post'=>array('with'=>'comments')),'avatar')->find_many();
```

It will make 3 querys:

```
SELECT * FROM user 
SELECT * FROM avatar WHERE user.id IN (......)
SELECT * FROM post WHERE user.id IN (.....)
```